# Which one is causing which: the HTTP/1.1" 500 error OR the TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, webserver

I am trying to figure out the root of the problem here. I have a dial_tone python app that I am trying to control its variable value (samp_rate) through a Flask webserver using a roundSlider widget embedded in an html script. When I run my Flask webserver the program seem to have no issues (but no tone yet)  then a few things will happen:

**First**: The app will start like this (which seems good so far):

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 269-962-008
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2019 14:22:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**Second**: When I start dragging the slider widget button I will get this Traceback:

```
gr::log :INFO: audio source - Audio sink arch: alsa
aUaUaUaU    127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2019 14:22:50] "GET /valueofslider?slide_val=1859 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
aUaUTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/fit-pc/my_flask_app/virtualenv/Slider/app.py", line 16, in slide
    return main(slide_val)
  File "/home/fit-pc/my_flask_app/virtualenv/Slider/app.py", line 25, in main
    samp_rate = int(slide_val) + 100
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

And thats where I get the confusion here, I see two issues here, this one:

```
7.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2019 14:22:50] "GET /valueofslider?slide_val=1859 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

And this one:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

**The interesting thing** here is while I am having this error I can hear the tone and the more I drag the slider the more the tone changes, though it was not in a constant way.
And I have no idea which one is causing the other here! Is it due the server connection error that has something to do with my browser or internet? Or, is it because the slide_val is not getting the input , due to the above server issue?

**What I tried so far:**

- I tried to use the error handlers, but no luck.
- I installed a different browsers on my linux mint machine and didn't help.

This this got me lost! Please, help me if you can.

Here is my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request,redirect,url_for
from random import randint
from top_block_22 import top_block_22

app = Flask(__name__)
# def test():
#     print("its working") 

@app.route('/')
def slide_func():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    slide_val = request.form.get('slide_val')
    return main(slide_val)   

# @app.errorhandler(404)
# def not_found_error(error):
#     return render_template('404.html'), 404

# @app.errorhandler(500)
# def internal_error(error):
#     db.session.rollback()
#     return render_template('500.html'), 500 
def main(slide_val):

    tb = top_block_22()
    tb.start()
    samp_rate = int(slide_val) + 100
    print(samp_rate)
    return(slide_val)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my main dial tone code:

```
from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for
from random import randint


class top_block_22(gr.top_block):

    def __init__(self):

    #def __init__(self, slide_val):


        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")        
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 32000

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN, 0.005, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))



def main(top_block_cls=top_block_22, options=None):


    tb = top_block_22()
    tb.start()
    try:
        raw_input('Press Enter to quit: ')
    except EOFError:
        pass
    tb.stop()
    tb.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

And this is my html script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery roundSlider - JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Only html needed   -->

  <div id="slider"></div>

  <script>
    var val;
    $("#slider").roundSlider({
      radius: 215,
        min: 0,
        max: 100000,
       change: function () {

        var obj1 = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
        val = obj1.getValue();
        value: 10
        $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
          slide_val: val
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send variable in url

```
/valueofslider?slide_val=1859
```

then you have it in `args`, not `form`

```
request.args.get('slide_val')
```

---

You may have it in `request.form` if you set it in `<form>` with `method="POST"`

If you use `<form>` with `method="GET"` (or without `method`) then you have it in `request.args`

Comment: "send variable in url"? like how, please?

Comment: I changed '@app.route('/valueofslider')' to '@app.route('/valueofslider?slide_val=1859')' then used 'args' I started getting the 'HTTP/1.1" 404' error.

Comment: don't change route. `args` are not used in route, they are removed from url before flask check routes.

Comment: you have to  change only `request.form.get('slide_val')` to  `request.args.get('slide_val')`

Comment: your suggestion removes both errors, updates the slider values correctly, but I cannot hear the tone anymore!

Comment: use `print()` to check variables in functions. Now you have different problem and you can create new question on new page.

Comment: You may problem with `samp_rate` - it is local variable which exists only in `main()` but you use it in `top_block_22`. In `top_block_22` you should get error similar to `"Variable 'samp_rate' doesn't exists."` You should rather send this value as parameter - ie. `tb = top_block_22(samp_rate)` and then get it inside `__init__`

Comment: if I run the top_block_22 itself it runs normally and I can hear the tone. The tone level changes whenever I change the samp_rate value manually and re-run the program again. The main() that I am referring to here is the top_block_22.

Comment: thanks for helping fixing the errors "furas", I will make a new thread about the new problem later.

Comment: You set manually `samp_rate` but it will not use `samp_rate` from `main()` - because it is local variable inside `main()` and other functions doesn't have access to this variable.

Comment: so what do suggest to fix that?

Comment: `tb = top_block_22(samp_rate)` and `def __init__(self, samp_rate):` - This way you send value as argument.

Comment: I updated my code based on your recommendation and posted a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57311774/wbserver-roundslider-widget-doesnt-start-update-audio-tone-program