# wbserver roundSlider widget doesn't start/update audio tone program

Tags: python, webserver

I have a "dial tone" python program that is imported into a Falsk webserver, and I have an html embedded roundSlider widget that I am trying to use to update the sample rate variable values inside dial tone program. Once I run the webserver and start dragging the slider, visually the value of the slider does update/change when dragging it, but there is no tone, the tone program doesn't start!

Please, I need your help to figure this out.

Here is my flask app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request,redirect,url_for
from random import randint
from top_block_22 import top_block_22

app = Flask(__name__)
# def test():
#     print("its working") 
@app.route('/')
def slide_func():
    return render_template("index.html")
    print(slide_val)
    return(slide_val)
def test():
    print("its working")

@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    slide_val = request.args.get('slide_val')
    return main(slide_val)   

def main(slide_val):

    tb = top_block_22()
    tb.start()
    samp_rate = int(slide_val) + 100
    print(samp_rate)
    return(slide_val)  
    app.debug = True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Main dial tone code:

```
from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio

from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for
from random import randint
#from app import *





class top_block_22(gr.top_block):

    def __init__(self, samp_rate):

        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")        
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 32000

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN, 0.005, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))



def main(top_block_cls=top_block_22, options=None):


    tb = top_block_22('samp_rate')

    tb.start()
    try:
        raw_input('Press Enter to quit: ')
    except EOFError:
        pass
    tb.stop()
    tb.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

index.html script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery roundSlider - JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Only html needed   -->
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('slide') }}">
  <div id="slider"></div>

  <script>
    var val;
    $("#slider").roundSlider({
      radius: 215,
        min: 0,
        max: 100000,
       change: function () {

        var obj1 = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
        val = obj1.getValue();
        value: 10
        $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
          slide_val: val
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is an image of the slider when its updating its values:

[image: slider]

Comment: remove `= 32000` and keep only `self.samp_rate = samp_rate`. And use it in `tb = top_block_22(32000)`

Comment: @furas, it didn't change the case. By the way, the way I run this is from my terminal on the same computer, is that the right way to do it? I mean everything on one computer!

Comment: Problem can be simply. It runs `top_block_22` for so short time that you can't hear sound. If you add ie. `time.sleep(2)` then you may hear sound. I run your code with  `time.sleep(2)` and hear sound but there is other problem and I don't know what is problem

Comment: @furas, where I should place this time.sleep(2)?

Comment: @furas, is there another approach to accomplish this project? I started to give on doing it through Flask and this roundSlider. Do you think there is a simpler approach?

Comment: if you want to run it on one computer then more natural could be use GUI instead of Web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me.

Main problem was that function runs so fast that nobody can hear sound - so I added `time.sleep(0.5)`

I put all code in one file so it is easier to copy and paste to file to run it.

Main page `http://localhost:5000/` displays few links with different values  to test it.

```
from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio

from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser


class top_block_22(gr.top_block):

    def __init__(self, samp_rate=32000): # default value for samp_rate

        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")        
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate   # without "= 32000"
        print('[DEBUG] top_block_22:', self.samp_rate)

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN, 0.005, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from flask import Flask, request
#from top_block_22 import top_block_22 
import time


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    HTML = 'HEAR:'
    for item in (20000, 25000, 32000):
        HTML += ' <a href="/valueofslider?slide_val={}">{}</a>'.format(item, item)
    return HTML

@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    slide_val = request.args.get('slide_val', 32000) # default value 32000
    main(slide_val)
    return slide_val

def main(slide_val):
    samp_rate = int(slide_val) + 100
    print('[DEBUG] main:', samp_rate)

    tb = top_block_22(samp_rate) # run with value from variable
    tb.start()

    time.sleep(0.5)

    tb.stop()
    tb.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

**EDIT:** This version displays slider and it uses `Thread` to play sound all time (after selecting first value on slider).

When slider sends new value then it stops old thread and creates new one with new `samp_rate`.

But maybe it can be done without `Thread` but using only `tb.start`, `tb.stop`, etc. It seems `top_block_22` already uses thread to work.

It also uses `http://localhost:5000/off` to send `samp_rate=0` which stop sound.

```
from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio

from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser


class top_block_22(gr.top_block):

    def __init__(self, samp_rate):

        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")        
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate
        print('[DEBUG] top_block_22:', self.samp_rate)

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN, 0.005, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from threading import Thread

class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, samp_rate):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = True
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate

    def run(self):

        tb = top_block_22(self.samp_rate)
        tb.start()

        while self.running:
            time.sleep(0.5)  # need it to head sound

        tb.stop()
        tb.wait()

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from flask import Flask, request
#from top_block_22 import top_block_22 
import time


app = Flask(__name__)

my_thread = None


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery roundSlider - JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Only html needed   -->
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('slide') }}">
  <div id="slider"></div>

  <script>
    var val;
    $("#slider").roundSlider({
      radius: 215,
        min: 0,
        max: 100000,
       change: function () {

        var obj1 = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
        val = obj1.getValue();
        value: 10
        $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
          slide_val: val
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>'''

@app.route('/off')
def off():
    '''use `slide_val=0` to turn it off'''
    main(0)
    return 'off'

@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    slide_val = request.args.get('slide_val', 32000)
    main(slide_val)
    return slide_val

def main(slide_val):
    global my_thread

    print('[DEBUG] main:', slide_val)
    samp_rate = int(slide_val)

    if my_thread: # if my_thread is not None
        my_thread.running = False
        my_thread.join()
        my_thread = None

    if samp_rate > 0:
        my_thread = MyThread(samp_rate)
        my_thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

**EDIT:** Version without `Thread`.

As before it display slider and it play sound all time after selecting first value. It use global value `tb` to keep access to object and stop it when  it get new `samp_rate`, and run new object.

It also uses `http://localhost:5000/off` to send `samp_rate=0` which stop sound.

```
from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio

from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser


class top_block_22(gr.top_block):

    def __init__(self, samp_rate):

        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")        
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate
        print('[DEBUG] top_block_22:', self.samp_rate)

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN, 0.005, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from flask import Flask, request
#from top_block_22 import top_block_22 


app = Flask(__name__)

tb = None  # global variable to keep it between requests


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery roundSlider - JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Only html needed   -->
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('slide') }}">
  <div id="slider"></div>

  <script>
    var val;
    $("#slider").roundSlider({
      radius: 215,
        min: 0,
        max: 100000,
       change: function () {

        var obj1 = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
        val = obj1.getValue();
        value: 10
        $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
          slide_val: val
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>'''

@app.route('/off')
def off():
    '''use `slide_val=0` to turn it off'''
    main(0)
    return 'off'

@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    slide_val = request.args.get('slide_val', 32000)
    main(slide_val)
    return slide_val

def main(slide_val):
    global tb

    print('[DEBUG] main:', slide_val)
    samp_rate = int(slide_val)

    # stop old sound
    if tb: # if tb is not None
        tb.stop()
        tb.wait()
        tb = None 

    # create new sound (if not zero)
    if samp_rate > 0:
        tb = top_block_22(samp_rate)
        tb.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

**EDIT:** last version

Few changes in JavaScript:

- it sets default value at start - 32000. There was mistake in JS.
- it sends request at start so it starts sound after loading page. There is no need to select value on slider.

Changes in Python:

- as suggest [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) I set `UpperCaseName` for class - `TopBlock22`
- renamed `main` to `sound` which better describe what function is doing
- `http://localhost/set/<value>` sets sample rate so it can be used instead of `http://localhost/valueofslider?slider_val=<value>`.
- `http://localhost/get` gets current sample rate
- `http://localhost/off` sets value to 0 so it turns off sound. I used it to fast turn off sound when it was too annoying.
- `print_function` from `__future__` to use `print(text)` like in Python 3
- functions return value as text but there are lines with `jsonify()` so they can retun it as JSON. Maybe it can be useful later.

In `FAQ` I found [How can I reconfigure a flow graph? How do I use lock(), unlock()?](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/FAQ#How_can_I_reconfigure_a_flow_graph.3F_How_do_I_use_lock.28.29.2C_unlock.28.29.3F) so maybe it can change sample rate without creating new object and maybe it gives better sound. I head click when it change sample rate.

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio

from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser


class TopBlock22(gr.top_block): # PEP8: CamelCaseName for classes

    def __init__(self, sample_rate=32000):

        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")        
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        print('[TopBlock22] sample_rate:', self.sample_rate)

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN, 0.005, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
#from top_block_22 import TopBlock22 
import time


app = Flask(__name__)

tb = None  # global variable to keep it between requests


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GNURadio Slider Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slider"></div>

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val;

  // create slider
  $("#slider").roundSlider({
    radius: 215,
    min: 0,
    max: 100000,
    value: 32000, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
      val = obj.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide_val: val
      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide_val: val});

</script>

</body>
</html>'''

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    HTML = 'HEAR:'
    for item in (0, 10000, 20000, 25000, 32000):
        HTML += ' <a href="/set/{}">{}</a>'.format(item, item)
    return HTML

@app.route('/off')
def off():
    """Turn off sound."""
    sound(0)
    #return jsonify({'val': 0})
    return 'off'

@app.route('/set/<int:value>')
def set_value(value):
    """Set value. Use 0 to turn it off."""
    sound(value)
    #return jsonify({'val': value})
    return str(value)

@app.route('/get')
def get_value():
    """Get current value."""
    if tb:
        value = tb.sample_rate
    else:
        value = 0
    #return jsonify({'val': value})
    return str(value)

@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    sample_rate = request.args.get('slide_val', '32000')
    sample_rate = int(sample_rate)
    sound(sample_rate)
    #return jsonify({'val': sample_rate})
    return str(sample_rate)

def sound(sample_rate):
    global tb

    print('[sound] sample_rate:', sample_rate)
    sample_rate = int(sample_rate)

    # stop old sound
    if tb: # if tb is not None
        tb.stop()
        tb.wait()
        tb = None 

    # create new sound (if not zero)
    if sample_rate > 0:
        tb = TopBlock22(sample_rate)
        tb.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

**EDIT:** this time last version.

It uses `lock/unlock` and `disconnect/connect` to change sound without creating new object. Based on example from FAQ ([How can I reconfigure a flow graph? How do I use lock(), unlock()?](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/FAQ#How_can_I_reconfigure_a_flow_graph.3F_How_do_I_use_lock.28.29.2C_unlock.28.29.3F)) but `disconnect` needed two endpoints like `connect`.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio

from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser


class TopBlock22(gr.top_block): # PEP8: CamelCaseName for classes

    def __init__(self, sample_rate=32000):

        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")        
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: sample_rate:', self.sample_rate)

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN, 0.005, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))

    def change(self, sample_rate):
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        print('[TopBlock22] change: sample_rate:', self.sample_rate)

        # lock
        self.lock()

        # disconect - needs two endpoints (not like in FAQ)
        self.disconnect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.disconnect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))

        # create new
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)

        # connect again
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))

        # unlock
        self.unlock()

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)

tb = None  # global variable to keep it between requests


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GNURadio Slider Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slider"></div>

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val;

  // create slider
  $("#slider").roundSlider({
    radius: 215,
    min: 0,
    max: 100000,
    value: 32000, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
      val = obj.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide_val: val
      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide_val: val});

</script>

</body>
</html>'''

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    HTML = 'HEAR:'
    for item in (0, 10000, 20000, 25000, 32000):
        HTML += ' <a href="/set/{}">{}</a>'.format(item, item)
    return HTML

@app.route('/off')
def off():
    """Turn off sound."""
    sound(0)
    #return jsonify({'val': 0})
    return 'off'

@app.route('/set/<int:value>')
def set_value(value):
    """Set value. Use 0 to turn it off."""
    sound(value)
    #return jsonify({'val': value})
    return str(value)

@app.route('/get')
def get_value():
    """Get value. Returns 0 when turned off."""
    if tb:
        value = tb.sample_rate
    else:
        value = 0
    #return jsonify({'val': value})
    return str(value)

@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    sample_rate = request.args.get('slide_val', '32000')
    sample_rate = int(sample_rate)
    sound(sample_rate)
    #return jsonify({'val': sample_rate})
    return str(sample_rate)

def sound_old(sample_rate):
    """version which doesn't use `change()`"""
    global tb

    print('[sound] sample_rate:', sample_rate)
    sample_rate = int(sample_rate)

    # stop old sound
    if tb: # if tb is not None
        tb.stop()
        tb.wait()
        tb = None 

    # create new sound (if not zero)
    if sample_rate > 0:
        tb = TopBlock22(sample_rate)
        tb.start()

def sound(sample_rate):
    """version which uses `change()`"""
    global tb

    print('[sound] sample_rate:', sample_rate)
    sample_rate = int(sample_rate)

    # change or stop old sound
    if tb: # if tb is not None
        if sample_rate > 0:
            tb.change(sample_rate)
        else:        
            tb.stop()
            tb.wait()
            tb = None 

    # create new sound (if not zero)
    if not tb:
        if sample_rate > 0:
            tb = TopBlock22(sample_rate)
            tb.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

**EDIT:** I found that `sample rate` can be change with

```
 self.analog_sig_source_x_1.set_sampling_freq(sample_rate)
```

so it doesn't have to create new `sig_source_f`

```
class TopBlock22(gr.top_block):

    # ... rest ...

    def change(self, sample_rate):
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        print('[TopBlock22] change: sample_rate:', self.sample_rate)

        self.analog_sig_source_x_1.set_sampling_freq(sample_rate)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_sampling_freq(sample_rate)
```

I think that now I don't hear clicks when it changes `sample rate` but now I fill it has small delay before it change it after mouse click.

To see other functions in this object you can use `dir(self.analog_sig_source_x_1)`

```
    print('\n'.join(dir(self.analog_sig_source_x_1)))

    ...        
    set_amplitude
    set_block_alias
    set_frequency
    set_max_noutput_items
    set_max_output_buffer
    set_min_noutput_items
    set_min_output_buffer
    set_offset
    set_processor_affinity
    set_sampling_freq
    set_thread_priority
    set_waveform
    ...
```

Source: [Choosing, defining and configuring blocks](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/TutorialsWritePythonApplications#Choosing.2C_defining_and_configuring_blocks), 
[documentation for C/C++ version](https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1analog_1_1sig__source__f.html)

Comment: That sounds great, but I will be limited with values range here. If we cannot have a slider here, can we have at least a sort of little box there that can take whatever values we want to input, then we hit enter button or something like that?

Comment: it is only example which everyone can easily copy and run it. But you can use it with your slider. Problem wasin't slider but `time.sleep()`

Comment: if you want to hear sound all time then you may have to run `top_block_22` in separated thread which will run all time. Normal version use `raw_input()` to run all time. Thread would use `while True` loop or `while running:` so you could stop it but setting `running = False`

Comment: I created version without `Thread` which play sound all time.

Comment: I am in a shock now! :D This one piece of code is my whole program, right? I tried and it works just like the way I wanted it! I can use it like that without having it in a separate files, right?

Comment: I can't really thank you enough. You are so nice, kind, generous, and talented. Thank you sooooooooooooooo much!

Comment: I played a bit with the code and I put last version.

Comment: This time last version. It use `lock/unlock` and `disconnect/connect` to change sound. I didn't check how it would work without `lock/unlock`.

Comment: I found `.set_sampling_freq(sample_rate)` for `analog.sig_source_f` and put code which use it.

Comment: I'm back. Man that's such an amazing work. I am going through the updates you added and I am speechless, you literally saved me! Again, thanks a LOT furas.

Comment: I was thinking about another version with more sliders which use `set_amplitude`, `set_frequency`, `set_waveform`, etc. but I skip this.

Comment: thats what I have to do next. Currently I am replicating the rounSlider widget to have 4 or 5 of them in my webpage because my next step is to build more variables sliders, i.e, CW, broadband noise, ...etc. This samp_rate was just the beginning for me to learn how it works and whether it can be done or not! But a HUGE thanks to you, I know now it works.

Comment: Thanks again furas.

Comment: Hi, I just posted a new thread about the same project, just another hardship :) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397344/a-problem-with-value-sliders-they-are-interfering-with-each-other