# A problem with value sliders, they are interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, webserver

I have a dial tone python code which runs via Flask webserver, there are a couple variables in my code that I am trying to control through roundSlider widgets. The problem that I am facing with is that when I start the program it runs normally and I can smoothly control the sample_rate variable through my first slider and can hear different tones while dragging the first slider. But when I start dragging the second slider to change the amplitude value, it does changes (start hearing noisy static sound) but at the same time it resets the sample rate tone/sound to original (though this doesn't mean it changes the first slider visually/dynamically).
Please, take a look at my code and see if you can help me with.

app.py code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser


class TopBlock22(gr.top_block): # PEP8: CamelCaseName for classes

    def __init__(self, sample_rate=32000, amplitude=0):

        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")        
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: sample_rate:', self.sample_rate)
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: amplitude:', self.amplitude)


        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440,  amplitude, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, amplitude, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN,  amplitude, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))

    def change(self, sample_rate, amplitude):
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: sample_rate:', self.sample_rate)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1.set_sampling_freq(self.sample_rate)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_sampling_freq(self.sample_rate)

    # def set_amplitude(self, amplitude):
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: amplitude:', self.amplitude)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1.set_amplitude(self.amplitude)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_amplitude(self.amplitude)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0.set_amplitude(self.amplitude)





        # lock
        self.lock()

        # disconect - needs two endpoints (not like in FAQ)
        self.disconnect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.disconnect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))

        # create new
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)

        # connect again
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))

        # unlock
        self.unlock()

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)

tb = None  # global variable to keep it between requests


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GNURadio Slider Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<style>

#slider1 {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:75px;
 align:center;
}
#slider2 {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:470px;
  align:center;
}
#slider3 {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:870px;
  align:center;
}
#slider4 {
 position:absolute;
 top:450px;
 left:75px;
  align:center;

}
#slider5 {
 position:absolute;
 top:450px;
 left:470px;
  align:center;
}
#slider6 {
 position:absolute;
 top:450px;
 left:870px;
  align:center;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>

<div id="slider1"></div>
<!--  <p>Sample Rate Slider</p> -->

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val;

  // create slider
  $("#slider1").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,

    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj = $("#slider1").data("roundSlider");
      val = obj.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide1_val: val

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide_val: val});

</script>
<div id="slider2"></div>
<!--  <p>Amplitude Slider2</p> -->
<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val;

  // create slider
  $("#slider2").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj = $("#slider2").data("roundSlider");
      val = obj.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide2_val: val

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide_val: val});

</script>
<div id="slider3"></div>
 <!-- <p>Frequency Slider3</p> -->

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val;

  // create slider
  $("#slider3").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj = $("#slider3").data("roundSlider");
      val = obj.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide3_val: val

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide_val: val});

</script>
<div id="slider4"></div>
 <!-- <p>Slider4</p>  -->

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val;

  // create slider
  $("#slider4").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
      val = obj.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide4_val: val

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide_val: val});

</script>
<div id="slider5"></div>
<!--  <p>Slider5</p>  -->

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val;

  // create slider
  $("#slider5").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
      val = obj.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide5_val: val

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide_val: val});

</script>
<div id="slider6"></div>
<!--  <p>Slider6</p>   -->

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val;

  // create slider
  $("#slider6").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
      val = obj.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide6_val: val

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide_val: val});

</script>

</body>
</html>'''

# @app.route('/test')
# def test():
#     HTML = 'HEAR:'
#     for item in (0, 10000, 20000, 25000, 32000):
#         HTML += ' <a href="/set/{}">{}</a>'.format(item, item)
#     return HTML

# @app.route('/off')
# def off():
#     """Turn off sound."""
#     sound(0)
#     #return jsonify({'val': 0})
#     return 'off'

@app.route('/set/<int:value>')
def set_value(value):
    """Set value. Use 0 to turn it off."""
    sound(value)
    #return jsonify({'val': value})
    return str(value)

@app.route('/get')
def get_value():
    """Get value. Returns 0 when turned off."""
    if tb:
        value = tb.sample_rate
        value = tb.amplitude
    else:
        value = 0
    #return jsonify({'val': value})
    return str(value)

@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    sample_rate = request.args.get('slide1_val', '32000')
    amplitude = request.args.get('slide2_val', '0')
    sample_rate = int(sample_rate)
    amplitude = int(amplitude)
    sound(sample_rate, amplitude)
    #return jsonify({'val': sample_rate})
    return str(sample_rate)
    return str(amplitude)

# def sound_old(sample_rate):
#     """version which doesn't use `change()`"""
#     global tb

#     print('[sound] sample_rate:', sample_rate)
#     sample_rate = int(sample_rate)

#     # stop old sound
#     if tb: # if tb is not None
#         tb.stop()
#         tb.wait()
#         tb = None 

    # create new sound (if not zero)
    if sample_rate > 0 & amplitude == 0:
            tb = TopBlock22(sample_rate, amplitude)
            tb.start()


def sound(sample_rate, amplitude):
    """version which uses `change()`"""
    global tb

    print('[sound] sample_rate:', sample_rate)
    sample_rate = int(sample_rate)
    print('[sound] amplitude:', amplitude)
    amplitude = int(amplitude)

    if tb: # if tb is not None
        if sample_rate > 0 & amplitude == 0 :
            tb.change(sample_rate, amplitude)

        else:        
            tb.stop()
            tb.wait()
            tb = None 

    # create new sound (if not zero)
    if not tb:
        if sample_rate > 0 & amplitude == 0:
            tb = TopBlock22(sample_rate, amplitude)
            tb.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Update:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser


class TopBlock22(gr.top_block): # PEP8: CamelCaseName for classes

    def __init__(self, sample_rate=32000, amplitude=0):

        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")        
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: sample_rate:', self.sample_rate)

        self.amplitude = amplitude
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: amplitude:', self.amplitude)
        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440,  amplitude, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, amplitude, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN,  amplitude, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))

    def change(self, sample_rate, amplitude=0):
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: sample_rate:', self.sample_rate)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1.set_sampling_freq(self.sample_rate)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_sampling_freq(self.sample_rate)


        self.amplitude = amplitude
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: amplitude:', self.amplitude)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1.set_amplitude(self.amplitude)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_amplitude(self.amplitude)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0.set_amplitude(self.amplitude)



        # lock
        self.lock()

        # disconect - needs two endpoints (not like in FAQ)
        self.disconnect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.disconnect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))

        # create new
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440, 0.4, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, 0.4, 0)

        # connect again
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))

        # unlock
        self.unlock()

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)

tb = None  # global variable to keep it between requests


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GNURadio Slider Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<style>

#slider1 {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:75px;
 align:center;
}
#slider2 {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:470px;
  align:center;
}
#slider3 {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:870px;
  align:center;
}
#slider4 {
 position:absolute;
 top:450px;
 left:75px;
  align:center;

}
#slider5 {
 position:absolute;
 top:450px;
 left:470px;
  align:center;
}
#slider6 {
 position:absolute;
 top:450px;
 left:870px;
  align:center;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>

<div id="slider1"></div>
<!--  <p>Sample Rate Slider</p> -->

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val1;

  // create slider
  $("#slider1").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,

    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj1 = $("#slider1").data("roundSlider");
      val1 = obj1.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide1_val1: val1

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide1_val: val1});

</script>
<div id="slider2"></div>
<!--  <p>Amplitude Slider2</p> -->
<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val2;

  // create slider
  $("#slider2").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj2 = $("#slider2").data("roundSlider");
      val2 = obj2.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide2_val2: val2

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide2_val: val2});

</script>
<div id="slider3"></div>
 <!-- <p>Frequency Slider3</p> -->

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val3;

  // create slider
  $("#slider3").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj3 = $("#slider3").data("roundSlider");
      val3 = obj3.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide3_val3: val3

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide3_val: val});

</script>
<div id="slider4"></div>
 <!-- <p>Slider4</p>  -->

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val4;

  // create slider
  $("#slider4").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj4 = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
      val4 = obj4.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide4_val4: val4

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide4_val: val});

</script>
<div id="slider5"></div>
<!--  <p>Slider5</p>  -->

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val5;

  // create slider
  $("#slider5").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj5 = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
      val5 = obj5.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide5_val5: val5

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide5_val: val});

</script>
<div id="slider6"></div>
<!--  <p>Slider6</p>   -->

<script>

  // keep slider's value
  var val;

  // create slider
  $("#slider6").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function () {
      var obj6 = $("#slider").data("roundSlider");
      val6 = obj6.getValue();
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide6_val6: val6

      });
    }
  });

  // play sound at start
  $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide6_val: val});

</script>

</body>
</html>'''



@app.route('/set/<int:value>')
def set_value(value):
    """Set value. Use 0 to turn it off."""
    sound(value)
    #return jsonify({'val': value})
    return str(value)

@app.route('/get')
def get_value():
    """Get value. Returns 0 when turned off."""
    if tb:
        value = tb.sample_rate
        value = tb.amplitude
    else:
        value = 0
    #return jsonify({'val': value})
    return str(value)

@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    sample_rate = request.args.get('slide1_val1', '32000')
    sample_rate = int(sample_rate)
    return str(sample_rate)

    if sample_rate > 0:
            tb = TopBlock22(sample_rate)
            tb.start()


def slide():

    amplitude = request.args.get('slide2_val2', '0')
    amplitude = int(amplitude)
    sound(sample_rate, amplitude)
    return str(amplitude)

    if amplitude == 0:
            tb = TopBlock22(amplitude)
            tb.start()

def sound(sample_rate, amplitude):
    """version which uses `change()`"""
    global tb

    print('[sound] sample_rate:', sample_rate)
    sample_rate = int(sample_rate)
    print('[sound] amplitude:', amplitude)
    amplitude = int(amplitude)

    if tb: # if tb is not None
        if sample_rate > 0 & amplitude == 0 :
            tb.change(sample_rate, amplitude)

        else:        
            tb.stop()
            tb.wait()
            tb = None 

    # create new sound (if not zero)
    if not tb:
        if sample_rate > 0 & amplitude == 0:
            tb = TopBlock22(sample_rate, amplitude)
            tb.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: When you send only amplitude then it change also sample rate to 32000 because there is `sample_rate = request.args.get('slide1_val', '32000')`. Better set to `None` and later use this None as inform to not change this value. Or better create separated functions for sliders, and separated functions in class TopBlock22. This way you always will work only with one value.

Comment: @furas, I updated my code (above) and created separated functions for sliders and separated functions in class TopBlock22 but I got no output.

Comment: you can't have two methods with the same name. You should get error. `__init__` should be only one - it only set value at start. You can't have two `change` - functions need different names - ie. `change_ampliture`, `change_sample_rate`.

Comment: In JavaScript you use the same variable for all sliders - `val` - they have to use variables with different names.

Comment: @furas, I updated it and re-posted it, still not sound!

Comment: by the way: again - you shouldn't have two functions with the same name - and you have two `def slide()`. You should get error message. And it shouldn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `TopBlock22` I have two methods: `change_sample_rate()` and `change_amplitude()` so I can change only one value and not care of other value.

In flask I have two functions with diferent names and different urls

```
@app.route('/set_sample_rate/<int:value>')
def set_sample_rate(value):
    tb.change_sample_rate(value)
    return str(value)

@app.route('/set_amplitude/<int:value>')
def set_amplitude(value):
    tb.change_amplitude(value)
    return str(value)
```

One of them changes sample rate using `TopBlock22.change_sample_rate()`, other changes amplitude using `TopBlock22.change_amplitude()`. This way every url change only one value and not care of other value.

And every slicer use different url to send value. This way every slicer change only one value and not care of other value.

---

I reduced few things to make it simpler.

First I create instance of `TopBlock22()` at start and not remove it when values are zero - so I don't have to check if it exists and recreate it.

I also reduced code in JavaScript. It doesn't use global variables to keep values. And it uses `event.value` to get value from slicer.

I also reduced CSS. I used classes `row1`, `row2`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3` to keep the same values (top, left) in one class.

I added button "Turn Off" which send zeros to server and also change values in slicers so they move to start position. It uses old function `/valueofslice` and `sound()` and `tb.change()` to change all values at once. It use `None` to control which value change so it can also change only one of values and not care of other values.

---

```
from __future__ import print_function
from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser


class TopBlock22(gr.top_block): # PEP8: CamelCaseName for classes

    def __init__(self, sample_rate=32000, amplitude=0, frequency=0):

        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block 22")
        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: sample_rate:', self.sample_rate)

        self.amplitude = amplitude
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: amplitude:', self.amplitude)

        self.frequency = frequency
        print('[TopBlock22] __init__: frequency:', self.frequency)

        # for mute_on, mute_off
        #self.old_sample_rate = self.sample_rate
        #self.old_ampliture = self.ampliture
        #self.old_frequency = self.frequency

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.blocks_add_xx = blocks.add_vff(1)
        self.audio_sink = audio.sink(32000, '', True)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_1 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 440,  amplitude, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, 350, amplitude, 0)
        self.analog_noise_source_x_0 = analog.noise_source_f(analog.GR_GAUSSIAN,  amplitude, -42)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_noise_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 2))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 0))
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_1, 0), (self.blocks_add_xx, 1))
        self.connect((self.blocks_add_xx, 0), (self.audio_sink, 0))

    def change_sample_rate(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            self.sample_rate = value
            print('[TopBlock22] change: sample_rate:', value)
            self.analog_sig_source_x_1.set_sampling_freq(value)
            self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_sampling_freq(value)

    def change_amplitude(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            value /= 10000.
            self.amplitude = value
            print('[TopBlock22] change: amplitude:', value)
            self.analog_sig_source_x_1.set_amplitude(value)
            self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_amplitude(value)
            self.analog_noise_source_x_0.set_amplitude(value)

    def change_frequency(self, value=None):
        if value is not None:
            self.frequency = value
            print('[TopBlock22] change: frequency:', value)
            #TODO: change some values

    def change(self, sample_rate=None, amplitude=None, frequency=None):
        #self.change_sample_rate(sample_rate)
        #self.change_amplitude(amplitude)
        #self.change_frequency(frequency)

        if sample_rate is not None:
            self.change_sample_rate(sample_rate)

        if amplitude is not None:
            self.change_amplitude(amplitude)

        if frequency is not None:
            self.change_frequency(frequency)

    def turn_off(self):
        self.change(0, 0, 0)

    #def mute_on(self):
    #    # remember values
    #    self.old_sample_rate = self.sample_rate
    #    self.old_ampliture = self.ampliture
    #    self.old_frequency = self.frequency
    #    # turn off sound
    #    self.change(0, 0, 0)

    #def mute_off(self):
    #    # set old values
    #    self.change(self.old_sample_rate, self.old_ampliture, self.old_frequency)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

# start with default values 
#tb = TopBlock22()
tb = TopBlock22(0, 0, 0)
tb.start()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GNURadio Slider Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<style>

.slider {
 position: absolute;
 align:center;
}    

.row1 {top:100px;}
.row2 {top:450px;}

.col1 {left:75px;}
.col2 {left:470px;}
.col3 {left:870px;}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="slider1" class='slider row1 col1'></div>
<!--  <p>Sample Rate Slider</p> -->

<div id="slider2" class='slider row1 col2'></div>
<!--  <p>Amplitude Slider2</p> -->

<div id="slider3" class='slider row1 col3'></div>
<!-- <p>Frequency Slider3</p> -->

<div id="slider4" class='slider row2 col1'></div>
<!-- <p>Slider4</p>  -->

<div id="slider5" class='slider row2 col2'></div>
<!-- <p>Slider5</p>  -->

<div id="slider6" class='slider row2 col3'></div>
<!-- <p>Slider6</p>  -->

<button id="turn_off_button">TURN OFF</button>

<script>

  // create sliders

  $("#slider1").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide1_val: event.value}); }
    change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/set_sample_rate/' + event.value); }
  });

  $("#slider2").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide2_val: event.value}); }
    change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/set_amplitude/' + event.value); }
  });

  $("#slider3").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide3_val: event.value}); }
    change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/set_frequency/' + event.value); }
  });

  $("#slider4").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide4_val: event.value}); }
  });

  $("#slider5").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide5_val: event.value}); }
  });

  $("#slider6").roundSlider({
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    change: function (event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide6_val: event.value}); }
  });

  $("#turn_off_button").click(function(){
      // set sliders
      $("#slider1").data("roundSlider").setValue(0);
      $("#slider2").data("roundSlider").setValue(0);
      $("#slider3").data("roundSlider").setValue(0);

      // send to server
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide1_val: 0,
        slide2_val: 0,
        slide3_val: 0,
      });
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>'''

@app.route('/off')
def off():
    """Turn off sound."""
    tb.turn_off()
    #return jsonify({'val': 0})
    return 'off'

@app.route('/set_sample_rate/<int:value>')
def set_sample_rate(value):
    #sound(sample_rate=value)
    tb.change_sample_rate(value)
    #return jsonify({'sample_rate': value})
    return str(value)

@app.route('/set_amplitude/<int:value>')
def set_amplitude(value):
    #sound(amplitude=value)
    tb.change_amplitude(value)
    #return jsonify({'amplitude': value})
    return str(value)

@app.route('/set_frequency/<int:value>')
def set_frequency(value):
    #sound(frequency=value)
    tb.change_frequency(value)
    #return jsonify({'frequency': value})
    return str(value)


@app.route('/valueofslider')
def slide():
    sample_rate = request.args.get('slide1_val', None)
    amplitude   = request.args.get('slide2_val', None)
    frequency   = request.args.get('slide3_val', None)

    sound(
        sample_rate=sample_rate, 
        amplitude=amplitude, 
        frequency=frequency,
    )

    #return jsonify({
    #        'sample_rate': sample_rate, 
    #        'amplitude': amplitude,
    #        'frequency ': frequency ,
    #        })

    return 'sample_rate: {}, amplitude: {}, frequency : {}'.format(sample_rate, amplitude, frequency )

def sound(sample_rate=None, amplitude=None, frequency=None):
    """version which uses `change()`"""

    if sample_rate is not None:
        sample_rate = int(sample_rate)
        tb.change_sample_rate(sample_rate)

    if amplitude is not None:
        amplitude = int(amplitude)
        tb.change_amplitude(amplitude)

    if frequency is not None:
        frequency = int(frequency )
        tb.change_frequency(frequency )

    print('[sound] sample_rate:', sample_rate)
    print('[sound] amplitude:', amplitude)
    print('[sound] frequency:', frequency)

    #if tb: # if tb is not None
    #    tb.change(sample_rate, amplitude, frequency)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: Again, I can't thank you enough man for your GREAT help! Thank you so much! I am trying to run the code but can't hear the tone!

Comment: I don't head tone when amplitude is 0. Probably the same is when sample_rate is 0. I have to move both slicers to hear tone. Problem can be also when it uses wrong values. `amplitude` probably has to float number in range [0,1] so I use `value /= 10000.` to get amplitude in this range [0,1]. There is dot in `10000.` to create float number. For integer value 1000 this `value /= 10000`  will always gives zero in Python 2.

Comment: Oh I see, I will re-study my GRC flowgraph and check the variables values and go from there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably my next thread will be about 'set_waveform' function. I would appreciate that if you help me with it once I post this topic. I didn't try to play around with it in the past a few days because honestly I didn't know how to do that. I mean the waveform menu in gnuradio, as you know, has list of string variables (constant, cosine, sine, square...) that I don't know how to include them in my code. But I will try to do my best!

Comment: I just got some updates on my task and I feel like I am getting confused here! Please, look and tell me if thats going far from what I have being doing: 
The SDR Python code needs to be able to output a user selectable waveform which can be a CW tone, Broadband Noise, or an arbitrary waveform read from a file containing I/Q values. For all of these waveforms user inputs should include the operating Frequency and bandwidth (except CW - frequency only). For the I/Q files the user will need to specify other parameters: number of samples and sample rate (there may be more).

Comment: I figured out a couple pieces of it :) , and will post a new thread about some issue that I am facing with.

Comment: I just posted a new thread. Kindly, at your convenience check my new thread, I am stuck with this problem since yesterday. link to new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443585/runtimeerror-lookuperror-keyerror-no-devices-found-for-device-address

Comment: Kindly, I have a new posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574305/python-flask-dat-file-upload